# VBA LongVar = range.find test if variable is empty

Tags: vba, find, range, long-integer, is-empty

I have the following code:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Test As String
Dim TestRow As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

Test = "Test"
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 
TestRow = ws.Range("B1:B" & LastRow).Find(What:=Test).Row
'This was entered after the first error
    If TestRow Is Empty Then
        ws.Range("B" & LastRow + 1) = Test
    End If
```

Without the If statement and Test is non-existent in my data I get the following error: 'runtime 91 object variable or with block variable not set'.

Next I'd like to test if TestRow is empty/zero I get a Type mismatch on TestRow. I've tried Is Nothing and various other options but I cant seem it to get it to work.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this instead:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Test As String
Dim TestRow As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

Test = "Test"
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set TestRow = ws.Range("B1:B" & LastRow).Find(What:=Test)

If TestRow Is Nothing Then
    ws.Range("B" & LastRow + 1) = Test
Else
    'Put code here if found Test (TestRow.Row is your row that it found it on)
End If
```

`Find` likes to return a `Range` so you need to `Dim` as a range and then `Set` the range.

Then we check if it found anything by the `TestRow Is Nothing` or `Not TestRow Is Nothing`.

Because you want the row then you would then use `TestRow.Row` for it's row number.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Was not aware `Find` was used to find a `Range` and not per se a `.row. `

My version seemed to work fine if:  

`TestRow = ws.Range("B1:B" & LastRow).Find(What:=Test).Row`

Was able to find something.

Comment: If your setting it to a variable as far as i know you need to set it as a range but you could just do it straight in an if statement and i think it works. Anyway if I’ve solved your problem and thats it for this it would be great if you could mark the answer as correct so this question essentially shows up as its been solved. Cheers.